# How to copy the default arguments of a function and initialize them as variables for debugging purposes in Python?

Tags: python

In my workflow I use Python interactively with Jupyter notebooks. Often I need to check some code inside a function with default arguments, e.g.

```py
def f (a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3):
   return a, b, c, d
```

In order to do this, I tipically run in new cells parts of the code inside the function and verify that everything is calculated correctly. However, because the default arguments are not stored in the memory, I need before to copy and paste them in another cell and initialize them. But I can not  just do:

```py
a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3
```

As I get:

```py
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal.
```

But I need to edit the different variables removing the commas and adding a change of line, as in:

```py
a = 0
b = 1
c = 2
d = 3
```

This is quite tedious when I have a lot of variables.

**Is there a Pythonic alternative to declare and initialize these variables in the same line without editing them?**

Answer (score 0):

In the debug console when you hit a breakpoint in `f` type

```
a,b,c,d = 0,1,2,3
```